# i got this error while loading excel file into tableau

Tags: excel, file, tableau-api, loading

i got this error while loading excel file into tableau.can anyone help on this

"Unable to complete action
Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
Error Code: 3834FD2B
Illegal file type for Excel protocol: "C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\My Tableau Repository\Workbooks\greendestination.csv"

road map for statistics

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to CSVs, select Text file, not Microsoft Excel.

[image]

Comment: Spot on and if you select Microsoft Excel, don't expect to see csv files listed in your open window.